# List of transit visa requirements

Tags: visas, twov

I'm writing a program that helps plan travel, mostly for people with passports on the not-so-good end of the Henley Index.  I need a table of countries x passport showing transit visa/TWOV requirements.
I'm finding any sort of tables of this sort of information quite hard to source. Does anyone have a suggestion of where to get such information faster and more durable than combing through state department websites?

Comment: There are entire companies based around maintaining such lists.  You're not going to find one readily available, and any data you do find from such systems will be copyright.  Also be ready to be sued when you get something wrong...

Comment: And the information is likely to go out of date, often and unpredictable.

Comment: If you follow this site, you will see that it is not a easy task: it depends on a lot of factors (and people have much diverse documents). Also "transit" is difficult to define properly (see again this site: not always you have transit, e.g. on separate tickets, between different terminals, between airports (and time: not at night, only 8, or 12 hours, etc.). And it depends on the documents you have (not just passport, but destination permits). Note that many cruise lines do not list requirements (Timatic is airline centric): and they have good contacts to immigration authorities!

Comment: "There are entire companies based around maintaining such lists" It would be useful to be pointed at some of these companies. We're a small nonprofit, but being a customer would be reasonable

Comment: @Anniepoo TIMATIC is the leading database that is maintained by IATA. you also have ICTS that maintains Traveldoc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only global resource I know of that’s more or less up to date is [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic), which is the database used by the airlines to determine requirements to allow boarding, under the auspices of IATA.

There are public user interfaces through some airlines or via the [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/), but as far as I know programmatic access requires a subscription, no idea about the fees for that.

Note that while the inputs are standardised (passenger nationality, documents, destination and transit countries, dates of travel, etc.), the output is not, given all the gazillion cases, exceptions, exceptions to exceptions, etc. Just for transit, the answer for a specific passenger nationality/country of transit combination can range from a single paragraph to multiple pages. While a lot of that information uses similar formats, there are tons of exceptions.

Timatic is also not foolproof, there have been errors in the past.

It’s actually very difficult to completely automate the task except for the simplest cases (I.e. you are likely to reject many options that are actually possible — though better that way than the other way around).

Don’t forget that this changes extremely often, sometimes at very short notice, and that new non-standard requirements can be added at any time (as we’ve seen a lot since the start of the Covid pandemic).

Make sure you do not give the impression to your users that an itinerary you suggest is guaranteed to be doable in their specific situation. That **will** get you in trouble. There is a reason nobody seriously tries to do this and deflects the responsibility on the passenger to look up the information themselves.

Another alternative, but with a lot more caveats, is Wikipedia, which have lots of pages titled “Visa Policy of XXX” and “Visa requirements for XXX citizens”. The advantage is that it’s free and you can probably easily download the data, but:

- I have no idea if all countries are covered
- It is less standard and more difficult to parse accurately
- It is probably not as up to date, though Wikipedia editors are always astonishing (but that may depend a lot on the country involved).

Comment: There are current errors/inaccuracies in Timatic as well. I've only used it through airlines' websites, but not a single one of them lists either A4 self-printed entry permits or immigration application receipts as a valid documentation for entering Cyprus, while people use them daily. Also, [some airlines](https://www.emirates.com/cy/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=cn&destination=cy) only mention Bulgarian C/D visas, but not residence permits.

Comment: Timatic is the most popular, but there are others. eg, ICTS TravelDoc and another who's name I can't remember at the moment...

Comment: @Doc do you know if it’s actually a separately maintained database, or could it be just a front-end to Timatic? Given the effort required to maintain that data and get updates from every country I am surprised that anything outside the IATA-managed solution could get all the necessary info timely.

Comment: Definitely different.  You can try it at www.traveldoc.aero

Comment: @Doc if you can remember that name now it would be useful